# Tag "tar" - isn't it mostly offtopic?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that most of the questions in tag [tar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tar) seem to be off-topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tar

For example, take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders). While tarring directories is definitely something that programmers do, this is also done by system administrators and regular Unix users. For this reason, I personally would migrate it to unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com. Where is the line for this kind of questions?

Comment: The question is not whether it is better on another site, the question is whether it is on-topic here on SO.  Additionally, the [Help] says on-topic can be "software tools commonly used by programmers."  Given that, I would say `tar` is in a gray area, but should be kept.

Comment: @JasonMArcher: How do programmers use it, other than preparing archives of their source codes, which just requires the basic command-line switches?